# Why i can't add in the array?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to add the values in an array, and than make an avarage.
But i notice that the values in array don't pass 256 when i make the sum.

```
SECTION .data   ;data section

array:      db  15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15
SIZE        EQU 20
    

;sum all positions of vector, length of 20

SECTION .text         ;code section

    global _start
    
    _start:

        xor bl,bl
        xor ecx,ecx
        jmp for_cond        
        
for_body:
        mov al,[array+ECX]
        add bl,al   
        inc ecx

for_cond:
        cmp ecx,SIZE
        jl  for_body    
        

        mov eax,1   ; exit command to kernel
        int 0x80    ; interrupt 80 hex, call kernel
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to add the whole sum in the `BL` register - which is only 8-bit wide and hence can only count up to 255. You better change your main loop to

```
for_body:
    movzx ax, byte [array+ECX]
    add   bx, ax   
    inc   ecx
```

This would realize the use of a 16-bit register that can count up to 65535. The `MOVZX` instruction will extend your 8-bit value from memory to a 16-bit value in `AX`. Then you can use a 16-bit register like `BX` or so to use for the final division by the number of elements (hold in `CX` or the constant `SIZE`).

**Note:**
If you use signed numbers instead of unsigned, you'd have to replace `MOVZX` by `MOVSX`.

Comment: i will try to put the values in a 16-bit register, thanks. I Forgot to put the label for_cond, but only cmp ecx with the SIZE and jl for_body

Comment: That's good. For further help, please try to make your code a [mcve]. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63385952/edit) your question accordingly.